# Creating a labelmatrix from a non-binary matrix for regionprops

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an RGB image that I've imported into MATLAB using imread(), and I have code that has converted each cells value from RGB values into a single value (e.g. going from [1;2;1] to [34]). I'm using this to record unique labels for each cell, which correspond to labels of object's I've segmented previously. A small section of the matrix would like this:

```
0 0  0  52 52 52 0  0  0
0 0  52 52 31 31 31 0  0
0 52 52 0  0  31 31 31 31
0 0  0  0  0  31 31 0  0
```

I'm currently trying to run regionprops on the matrix with single values, thinking it would automatically interpret the matrix as a labelmatrix. This doesn't seem to be the case though as the 'label' property is not present in the output. I have areas in my matrix where objects are touching each other, and thus converting the single matrix to binary and running regionprops on that will lead to unwanted merging of objects.
Is there a way to get regionprops to recongize my matrix as a labelmatrix as-is? Or at least convert my matrix into a labelmatrix?

Comment: It [should](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#buoixjn-1-L) recognize it; and in a simple test it [does](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/QsFWIdpQAQQNFAysYQwFI2swBWQoGMXqKFQClRWlpmfm5xUU5RcUa1ToKKg7FqUmqmsC5fRArP//AQ). We are going to need a reproducible example that illustrates your problem

Comment: You're right - I was looking for a LabelNames output based on this message from the function documentation "
 
"If the input image is a categorical label image L, then stats includes an additional field or variable with the property "LabelName""

I missed the categorical variable part, I thought it would keep the labels even if they were integer based. Thanks!